# Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm newbie to `pyspark`, last day I drew crime data to map and it worked fine, today I'm facing this issue.

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
>   : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 5.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 8, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException

this is full traceback

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-a4ce64abb6b1> in <module>()
 43     gmap.scatter(t_lat, t_lng, '#8A15DE', size=40, marker=False)
 44     gmap.draw('crimefile.html')
---> 45 init()

<ipython-input-2-a4ce64abb6b1> in init()
 34 
 35     gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(41.881832, -87.623177, 16).from_geocode('Chicago')
---> 36     lat = parsedData.filter(lambda x: x.Primary_Type == 'BATTERY' and x.Year == '2015')                    .map(lambda x:float(x.Latitude)).collect()
 37     lng = parsedData.filter(lambda x: x.Primary_Type == 'BATTERY' and x.Year == '2015')                   .map(lambda x:float(x.Longitude)).collect()
 38 

/Users/Mubin/Spark/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in collect(self)
807         """
808         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
--> 809             port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
810         return list(_load_from_socket(port, self._jrdd_deserializer))
811 

/Users/Mubin/Spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/Users/Mubin/Spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.pyc in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/Users/Mubin/Spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:     Task 5 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 5.0 in     stage 3.0 (TID 8, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Mubin/Spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 174, in main
process()
  File "/Users/Mubin/Spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 169, in process
serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File     "/Users/Mubin/Spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 268, in dump_stream
vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "<ipython-input-2-a4ce64abb6b1>", line 36, in <lambda>
 ValueError: could not convert string to float: 

at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.next(PythonRDD.scala:156)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.next(PythonRDD.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.next(InterruptibleIterator.scala:43)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:935)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:935)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
at  org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1944)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1958)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:935)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:934)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:453)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Mubin/Spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 174, in main
process()
File "/Users/Mubin/Spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 169, in process
serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
File    "/Users/Mubin/Spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 268, in dump_stream
vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
File "<ipython-input-2-a4ce64abb6b1>", line 36, in <lambda>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 

at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.next(PythonRDD.scala:156)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.next(PythonRDD.scala:152)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.next(InterruptibleIterator.scala:43)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.to(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toBuffer(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.toArray(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:935)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:935)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1944)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
... 1 more
```

Here is my code.

```
import csv
from StringIO import StringIO
from collections import namedtuple
from gmplot import *
Crime = ''
def loadData():
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
    filePath = '/Users/Mubin/SparkData/chicago.csv'
    return sc.textFile(filePath)
def parse(row):
    global Crime
    reader = csv.reader(StringIO(row))
    row = reader.next()
    return Crime(*row)
def prepareHeaders(header):
    return header.replace(' ', '_').replace('/', '_').split(',')

def createNamedTuple(header):
    return namedtuple('Crime', header, verbose=False)
def init():
    global Crime
    chicago = loadData()
    headers = chicago.first()
    #return chicago.first()
    woHeaders = chicago.filter(lambda x:x <> headers)
    #prepare headers[remove spaces, slaches] and convert to list.
    fields = prepareHeaders(headers)
    Crime = createNamedTuple(fields)
    #map header to tuples data to access properties as object.
    parsedData = woHeaders.map(parse)
    #return parsedData.take(1)
    #return parsedData.map(lambda x:x.Primary_Type).countByValue()
    #return parsedData.filter(lambda x:x.Primary_Type == 'BATTERY').map(lambda x:x.Year).countByValue()

    gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(41.881832, -87.623177, 16).from_geocode('Chicago')
    lat = parsedData.filter(lambda x: x.Primary_Type == 'BATTERY' and x.Year == '2015')\
                .map(lambda x:float(x.Latitude)).collect()
    lng = parsedData.filter(lambda x: x.Primary_Type == 'BATTERY' and x.Year == '2015')\
               .map(lambda x:float(x.Longitude)).collect()

    t_lat = parsedData.filter(lambda x: x.Primary_Type == 'THEFT' and x.Year == '2015')\
                .map(lambda x:float(x.Latitude)).collect()
    t_lng = parsedData.filter(lambda x: x.Primary_Type == 'THEFT' and x.Year == '2015')\
               .map(lambda x:float(x.Longitude)).collect()

    gmap.scatter(lat, lng, '#DE1515', size=40, marker=False)
    gmap.scatter(t_lat, t_lng, '#8A15DE', size=40, marker=False)
    gmap.draw('crimefile.html')
init()
```

if I uncomment any return line, it just returns data fine, but I'm unable to draw maps anymore.

Thanks.

Comment: `gmap.draw('crimefile.html')` is a byte array or static file ? All request waiting a answer(or header). Try sending some data/header or redirector page on waiting time. `None` isn't acceptable value for `java` !

Comment: @dsgdfg: yesterday it was working fine and created file using `gmap.draw('crimefile.html')` now it is not; can you refer how can I pass header to gmap library before creating file?

Comment: Is x.Year a string or numeric type? i.e does this work `lat = parsedData.filter(lambda x: x.Primary_Type == 'BATTERY' and x.Year == 2015).map(lambda x:float(x.Latitude)).collect()`

Comment: Alternatively is there a reason that the cast for your x.Latitude `.map(lambda x:float(x.Latitude)).collect()` - has it been parsed incorrectly or does a line in the file contain corrupt data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting is

> ValueError: could not convert string to float

My best guess is that you're trying to convert `string` values to `float` without filtering empty values(I can't find it in your code). So in your code, do something like this for both `Latitude` and `Longitude`.

```
lambda x: x.Primary_Type == 'NARCOTICS' and x.Latitude != ''
```

Hope this will help.