# Pyspark in databricks with 10m rows: job stage failure - executor driver error

Tags: sql, database, pyspark, databricks, random-forest

I've seen a lot of stackoverflows on this topic, but most of them suggest config manpulation, which i've already tried.

I am running on a standard default cluster in databricks. I'm importing a pretty large table (7m rows), but so far I've been operating on it without a problem using pyspark and other libraries.

However, When I try to run a random forest classification, I get an error. Somewhere, there's a data overflow. I'm not sure where. See the code below for more details.

If it's worth looking at, I'm trying to run this model that causes the failure:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F 
import pyspark.sql.types as t

#new column with the avatar_index as double 
user_sessions_df = user_sessions_df.withColumn("avatar_index", F.col("avatar").cast("Double"))

#increase number of partitions 
user_sessions_df = user_sessions_df.repartition(131072)

#drop the features column 
user_sessions_df =user_sessions_df.drop("features")

#feature vector 
vector_assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=['player_name', 'scene_id', 'date', 'year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'avatar_index'],outputCol="features")

#convert  data types of features to numeric 
user_sessions_df = user_sessions_df.withColumn("player_name", F.when(condition=((user_sessions_df["player_name"] != "") & (user_sessions_df["player_name"].isNotNull()) & (user_sessions_df["player_name"] != None)),value=F.col("player_name").cast("Double")).otherwise(-1))
user_sessions_df = user_sessions_df.withColumn("scene_id", F.when(condition=((user_sessions_df["scene_id"] != "") & (user_sessions_df["scene_id"].isNotNull()) & (user_sessions_df["scene_id"] != None)),value=F.col("scene_id").cast("Double")).otherwise(-1))
user_sessions_df = user_sessions_df.withColumn("date", F.when(condition=((user_sessions_df["date"] != "") & (user_sessions_df["date"].isNotNull()) & (user_sessions_df["date"] != None)),value=F.col("date").cast("Double")).otherwise(-1))  


user_sessions_df = vector_assembler.transform(user_sessions_df)


(train_df, test_df) = user_sessions_df.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])

#create rf 
rf_classifier = RandomForestClassifier(labelCol="session_count", featuresCol="features", numTrees=128)

#rf 
model = rf_classifier.fit(train_df) predictions = model.transform(test_df) evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(labelCol="session_count", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="accuracy")

accuracy = evaluator.evaluate(predictions) print("Accuracy = {}".format(accuracy))
```

I'm configured like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext 
from pyspark import SparkContext 
from pyspark import SparkConf


conf = SparkConf()


conf.set("spark.executor.instances", "1024")
conf.set("spark.executor.cores", "1024")


conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "1024g")
conf.set("spark.driver.memory", "2048")


conf.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "512g")
conf.set("spark.executor.maxResultSize", "512")


conf.set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max.mb", "131072")
conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "262144")


#Increase the Number of Cores for Task Scheduler (Default - 1, Increase to 2 or 4)**  
conf.set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
conf.set("spark.scheduler.allocation.file", "fairscheduler.xml")
```

I get one of two errors here:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 82.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task
3.0 in stage 82.0 (TID 108) 

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 173.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task
0.0 in stage 173.0 (TID 238) (ip-10-156-234-195.ec2.internal executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: [FAILED_EXECUTE_UDF] Failed to execute user defined function (StringIndexerModel$$Lambda$7385/614759719: (string) => double)
```

I also checked the cluster logs:

```
2023-02-25T16:14:35.992+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 2221216K->128K(4408320K)] 11188558K 8983958K(17633280K), 0.0409329 secs] [Times: user=0.12 sys=0.01, real=0.04 secs]  

2023-02-25T16:14:37.480+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 2204800K-160K(4408320K)] 11188630K->8984070K(17633280K), 0.0381262 secs] [Times: user=0.11 sys=0.01, real=0.04 secs]  

2023-02-25T16:14:38.966+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 2204832K-128K(4408320K)] 11188742K->8984118K(17633280K), 0.0270294 secs] [Times: user=0.10 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs]  

2023-02-25T16:14:40.435+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 2204800K-65696K(4408320K)] 11188790K->9049742K(17633280K), 0.0335045 secs] [Times: user=0.12 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs]  

2023-02-25T16:14:41.958+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 2270368K-160K(4527616K)] 11254414K->9180894K(17752576K), 0.1504603 secs] [Times: user=0.33 sys=0.15, real=0.16 secs]  

2023-02-25T16:14:43.671+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 2324128K-65728K(4408320K)] 11504862K->9246550K(17633280K), 0.0338819 secs] [Times: user=0.13 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs]  

2023-02-25T16:14:45.308+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 2389696K-164000K(4813312K)] 11570518K->9410462K(18038272K), 0.0868608 secs] [Times: user=0.31 sys=0.03, real=0.09 secs]  2023-02-25T16:14:47.348+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 3031200K-131264K(4665856K)] 12277662K->9574398K(17890816K), 0.1293894 secs] [Times: user=0.26 sys=0.13, real=0.13 secs]  

2023-02-25T16:14:54.775+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 2998464K-542977K(4977664K)] 12441598K->10117288K(18202624K),0.1547034 secs] [Times: user=0.42 sys=0.09, real=0.16 secs]  

2023-02-25T16:14:55.789+0000: [GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 3852033K-3392K(4943360K)] 13426344K->10248792K(18168320K), 0.3667542 secs] [Times: user=0.53 sys=0.52, real=0.36 secs]
```

I've tried manipulating existing pyspark configs and increasing partitions, as above. Cluster restart does not resolve the issue. I have been able to work with this data in pyspark so far, but this RF model causes some data failure.

I have seen some references to a jar file. Do i need one? [Pyspark/Databricks - org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56926564/pyspark-databricks-org-apache-spark-sparkexception-job-aborted-due-to-stage-f)

My best guess is it's something like this, but i'm not sure what: [Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41974532/job-aborted-due-to-stage-failure-task-5-in-stage-3-0-failed-1-times)

Comment: `user_sessions_df.repartition(131072)`
why do you use so many partitions? seems suspicious, although I never did this. It's commonly expected say 10 partitions per executor, not 1000

Comment: Oh, and it seems that you asked for 1k cores for each of 1k executors.. spark.executor.cores means how many cores will be allocated for one exectuor

Comment: Ha yes - I learned to use 2^n units as applicable so i was incrementally increasing every config value I could basically. I think it had some effect, because my error would change from the UDF to another task loss. But i'm not sure that's true.